# What does variable "group", "order", "subregion" mean in the "counties" database in "maps" package?

Tags: r, maps, geo

I am trying to append the longitude and latitude data in the "county" database with my geo data. However, I see there are also variables named "group" "order" "subregion" in the "counties" dataset in the maps package, and there is no corresponding description in the help file. Does anyone has any clue about this? Thanks!

Below is a small part of the "county" database.

long        lat         group   order   region  subregion

-86.50517   32.34920    1       1       alabama autauga

-86.53382   32.35493    1       2       alabama autauga

What I want to get is a colored map of populations of different counties in US. I have a separate database of the population and counties, I just want to append longitude and latitude data to my database so that I can use the ggplot2 package to do mapping.

I am totally new to plot geo-map with R, any suggestions and ideas are welcome!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be great if you can provide a bit of your data. If you can provide your code (what you have tried so far), that would be great . You are likely to have more help when you provide them. Meanwhile I think group and order are important when you draw polygons in your map.

Comment: How about reading [this link](http://www.bertplot.com/visualization/?p=429)? If you search more, you would be able to find more information.